# Как сделать цикл, чтобы переместить элементы внутри каждого отдельного родителя?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу переместить блок внутрь соседнего блока, внутри родителя, но у меня несколько блоков с одинаковыми классами, как сформулировать цикл, чтобы блок перемещался только внутри определенного родителя?

а то сейчас у меня внутрь каждого блока сразу все блоки со всех одноименных встают.

```js
$(".why-main-item").prependTo(".why-main-item-title");
```

```html
<div class="why-main-item">

  <div class="why-main-item-ico">
    <img src="<?=$img?>" <?if ($img_alt !="" ) {?>alt="
    <?=$img_alt?>"
      <?}?>>
  </div>

  <div class="why-main-item-title">
    <?=$why->post_title?>
  </div>

  <div class="why-main-item-txt">
    <?=$why->post_content?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: мне нужно чтобы (".why-main-item-txt") перемещался внутрь (".why-main-item-title"), подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно указать в коде?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".why-main-item-txt").each(function () {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".why-main-item").find(".why-main-item-title"));
        });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]